# Why does camera set mode fails with time out?

Tags: dji-sdk

What is the reason for the below function returning onResult with dji error (drone and remote are connected), usually it works but fails from time to time...

calling: DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct().getCamera().setMode(SettingsDefinitions.CameraMode.MEDIA_DOWNLOAD,listener)

result: Execution of this process has timed out(255)